# Saving file to network folder using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save file to a folder on the server. I am running the application locally on Cassini-Local Dev Server and saving the file on the server where the app is hosted on IIS.  The folder allows network service to create/read/write files to this folder.

```
  string destinationPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}\\", @"\\server\G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files\", uploadDate.ToString("yyyy"), uploadDate.ToString("MMM"), uploadDate.ToString("dd"));

 if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

                        //Save File To Folder
                        string storedFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", destinationPath, System.Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToUpper());
                        file.SaveAs(storedFileName);
                        miscFile.FileStoredName = storedFileName;
```

I keep on getting the error

> The given path's format is not supported

Comment: The AppPool also need access rights to the folder.

Comment: @"\\server\G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files\" = I don't think this will work, the folder must be shared and you should be able to access the folder as @"\\server\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files\"

Comment: Its a folder on the server where application is hosted. I believe the AppPool has acess rights to the folder because the folder allows access to network service and I am running it locally. Even ran it under IIS locally and same issue

Comment: if the path is within the server as well, you don't need to specify the server to access the folder, just by doing a @"G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files\" should do well for you

Comment: @kenlacoste I removed the name of the server and now getting Could not find a part of the path

Comment: from the looks of it, it seems you're having 4 backslashes between {0}\\{1}, please remove the last backslash in your string parameter destination..change should be something like this @"G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files\" to @"G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files"

Comment: `@"\\server\G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files\"` should probably drop the trailing slash: `@"\\server\G:\xyz\xyStore\uploads\Files"` since the format specifier includes it.

Comment: I would first suggest that you try the path right from say `Explorer` on the server ... for example the `G:` will most likely not work - usually you have administrative auto-shares for the drives but those would be `\\server\G$\xyz\...`` but you really should not use them - instead you should share the folder on the target server with a good name and valid read/write rights (why do you want to create directories there?)

Comment: This is where it tries to create a directory and its fails and gives the error that "could not find a part of the path". It doesn't mater if I remove the server name G:\\FolderA\\FolderB\\FolderC\\FolderD\\2015\\Oct\\20\\"

Comment: I cant access from explorer because my request is being processed by help desk. But the app should have access because the folder allows network service to create. I want to create Directories because I save my file based on Year, Month\ Day

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect your network folder first. We have something similar to your needs

```
    public void ConnectToUnc(string remoteUnc, string userName, string passwrod)
    {
        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
        // Disk
        nr.dwType = 0x00000001;
        nr.lpRemoteName = remoteUnc;

        // Try to connect to remote UNC (non-interactive, withod drive mapping)
        int ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, passwrod, userName, 0, null, null, null);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error connecting to UNC: " + ret);
        }
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(remoteUnc);
    }
```

Import of Windows API

```
    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
        IntPtr hwndOwner,
        NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
        string lpPassword,
        string lpUserID,
        int dwFlags,
        string lpAccessName,
        string lpBufferSize,
        string lpResult
        );


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class NETRESOURCE
    {
        public int dwScope = 0;
        public int dwType = 0;
        public int dwDisplayType = 0;
        public int dwUsage = 0;
        public string lpLocalName = "";
        public string lpRemoteName = "";
        public string lpComment = "";
        public string lpProvider = "";
    }
```

[Link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)